# When opening a plain text file with Chrome, how can I know how many lines the text contains?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, newlines, statistics, plaintext

I'd prefer not having to copy the text to another program, as it may be very large ([example](https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/sarulab-speech/jtubespeech/master/data/ja/202103.csv)).

Comment: On linux: `curl https://example.com/foo.csv | wc -l`

Comment: @mashuptwice thanks, I'd like to stay in chrome if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> (or Right Click, then `View page source`) will display the source with line numbers:

[image]

Thanks to Reddit user [ThatFreeSpirit](https://www.reddit.com/user/ThatFreeSpirit) for the trick.